# elfinder not displaying directories of AWS S3 with Laravel

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-s3, elfinder

I am using barryvdh elfinder package to display all the files and folders from my AWS S3 bucket. In elfinders config I have defined root as follows:

```
[
'driver' => 'Flysystem',
            'path'       => '',
            'defaults'   => array('read' => true, 'write' => true),
            'filesystem' => new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem(
                new \League\Flysystem\AwsS3v2\AwsS3Adapter( \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
                'key'    => 'key',
                'secret' => 'secret'
            )), 'bucket-name'))
]
```

This seems to work fine, all the files are being displayed. But the folders are not being listed. If I create a folder, it shows error message, but the folder is being created in the bucket, only it doesnt show any folders.
Can anyone help me with the solution.